# How to remove a specific parameter from the URL in PHP?

Tags: php

Example:

```
$url = http://example.com/?arg=val&arg2=test&arv3=testing&arv2=val2  
remove_url_arg($url, "arg2")
echo($url); // http://example.com/?arg=val&arv3=testing
```

The above `remove_url_arg`() function removes all occurrence of `arg2` argument from the URL

Answer (score 3):

```
unset($_GET['arg2']);
$query_string = http_build_query($_GET);
```

if it's not on request but to parse whole url

```
$parsed = parse_url($url);
$qs_arr = parse_str($parsed['query'],1);
unset($qs_arr['arg2']);
$parsed['query'] = http_build_query($qs_arr);
```

and then assemble the url back.

or one-liner regexp