# Remove specific parameter from URL while preserving other parameters

Tags: php, regex

I want remove a parameter from a URL:

```
$linkExample1='https://stackoverflow.com/?name=alaa&counter=1';
$linkExample2='https://stackoverflow.com/?counter=4&star=5';
```

I am trying to get this result:

- https://stackoverflow.com/?name=alaa&
- https://stackoverflow.com/?&star=5

I am trying to do it using `preg_replace`, but I've no idea how it can be done.

Comment: try and use parse_url() function. It breaks up the url into parts so you can check and modify it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove a specific parameter from the URL in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543826/how-to-remove-a-specific-parameter-from-the-url-in-php)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$link = preg_replace('~(\?|&)counter=[^&]*~','$1',$link);
```

Comment: Thanks Crayon but i got this error 
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 19 in C:\AppServ\www\pa.php on line 6

Comment: Thanks alot, but can i remove the & before or after the value?

Comment: technically your question and example output asked for it.  But FYI it is okay to leave those there.  But if you nonetheless want something "cleaner" then I suggest looking at the answers involving `parse_url` and `http_build_query` instead

Comment: The problem is, i am using a url rewrite and i can't use http_build_query, Your function is works fine now, Thanks again

Comment: This works for me! After the preg_replace I used `$link = rtrim($link, '?&');` to remove the last sign of the link, if it is a "?" or an "&". :)

Answer (score 3):

Relying on regular expressions can screw things up sometimes..

You should use, the `parse_url()` function which breaks up the entire URL and presents it to you as an associative array.

Once you have that array, you can edit it as you wish and remove parameters.

Once, completed, use the `http_build_url()` function to rebuild the URL with the changes made.

Check the docs here..

[Parse_Url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)  [Http_build_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php)

**EDIT**

Whoops, forgot to mention. After you get the parameter string, youll obviously need to separate the parameters as individual ones. For this you can supply the string as input to the [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function.

You can even use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with & as the delimeter to get this done.

Comment: afaik the only time it would screw up is if the url was malformed to begin with. If that is the case, those built-in functions would fail as well.  GIGO.

Comment: agreed. in extreme cases then, it would be best to split the url string at the '=' sign and split the second part using explode using the & delimiter

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a combination of [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [http_build_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

Comment: yep!  it seems cleaner than regex for this.

Comment: after i parsed the url,using parse_url(), i got this results.. [query] => name=alaa&counter=1.. ANd This is not useful.. please read question again

Comment: you actually need to use `parse_url()` to get the query string, then `parse_str()` to put the query string params into an array,  then check and remove the url param index if it exists, and then `http_build_query()` to rebuild the query string

Comment: you can always use the explode function on this string and put in the delimeter as '&'. This will give you all the parameter as an array.

Comment: my urls is looks like this //http://link.com/category/something/page/1.html and i can't rebuild the link again.. it's so hard

Answer (score 1):

A code example how I would grab a requested URL and remove a parameter called "name", then reload the page:

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //complete url
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query); //grab the query part
unset($query['name']); //remove a parameter from query
$dest_query = http_build_query($query); //rebuild new query
$dest_url=(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http").'://'.$parts['path'].'?'.$dest_query; //add query to host
header("Location: ".$dest_url); //reload page
```

Answer (score 1):

## Handle it correctly! !

```
remove_query('http://example.com/?a=valueWith**&amp;**inside&b=value');
```

Code:

```
function remove_query($url, $which_argument=false){ 
    return preg_replace( '/'. ($which_argument ? '(\&|)'.$which_argument.'(\=(.*?)((?=&(?!amp\;))|$)|(.*?)\b)' : '(\?.*)').'/i' , '', $url);  
}
```

Comment: works like charm

Answer (score 0):

`parse_url()` and `parse_str()` are buggy.  Regular expressions can work but have the tendency to break.  If you want to correctly deconstruct, make changes, and then reconstruct a URL, you should look at:

http://barebonescms.com/documentation/ultimate_web_scraper_toolkit/

`ExtractURL()` generates `parse_url()`-like output but does much more (and does it right).  `CondenseURL()` takes an array from `ExtractURL()` and constructs a new URL from the information.  Both functions are in the 'support/http.php' file.

Answer (score 0):

Years later...
[$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) can be manipulated like any other array in PHP. Simply [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) the key and create the http query using the [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function.

```
// Populate _GET with sample data...
$_GET = array(
    'value_a' => "A",
    'key_to_remove' => "Don't delete me bro!",
    'value_b' => "B"
);
// Should output everything...
// "value_a=A&key_to_remove=Don%27t+delete+me+bro%21&value_b=B"
echo "\n".http_build_query( $_GET );

// Remove the key from _GET...
unset( $_GET[ 'key_to_remove' ] );
// Should output everything else...
// "value_a=A&value_b=B"
echo "\n".http_build_query( $_GET );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
function removeParameterFromUrl($url, $key)
{
    $parsed = parse_url($url);
    $path = $parsed['path'];
    unset($_GET[$key]);
    if(!empty(http_build_query($_GET))){
      return $path .'?'. http_build_query($_GET);
    } else return $path;
}
```

Comment: You're parsing $url, but then using $_GET instead... are you sure it's working for you?