# Remove specific URL parameter

Tags: php

Say I have the following URL:

```
http://example.com/safety-checks/?carid=63&interval=2
```

And am getting the current url by doing

```
$current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

How would I go about stripping the &interval=# but leaving the carid value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove specific parameter from URL while preserving other parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985433/remove-specific-parameter-from-url-while-preserving-other-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

This should return up to the carid. The ampersand and everything following it is removed.
`$noInterval = explode("&", $current_url)[0]`